# Which objects the with statement applies to?

Tags: python, variables, with-statement, statements

I am fairly new in Python. I think to rename objects like the classical

```
with open('filename','r') as f
   ...
```

is very handy and I would like to do the same with many other objects but it fails, for instance, in

```
dic={'a':1}                   
with dic as x
    pass
```

with the error: `AttributeError: __enter__`

I would like to know why it works in the first example but not in the second one.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not merely "renaming". RTFM: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with

Comment: Any object that has an `__enter__` and `__exit__` method is a *context manager*. The purpose of `with something as x` is **not for renaming**.